# Restore mongodb <3.0 data files (.ns, .0, .1) in mongodb 3.4

Tags: mongodb

On a two year old server backup I found a couple of MongoDB collections that I need to restore in a current version of MongoDB (e.g. v3.4). Unfortunately, the `mongod --dbpath` flag is not supported anymore so that collections stored in .ns, .0, and .1 files can not be dumped and restored as intended.

Do I need a older version of MongoDB (<3.0.0) in order to dump these data files or is there a more salient solution for data migration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original [MMAPv1 storage engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/mmapv1/) is still available in MongoDB 3.4, it's just no longer the default storage engine.

If you want to read MMAP data files created by an older version of MongoDB you can either:

1. Start up a new instance of `mongod` with the [`--storageEngine mmapv1`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-storageengine) parameter (or config file equivalent) and use MongoDB 3.4's `mongodump` to export the required collection(s).
2. Use the `mongodump` utility from MongoDB 2.6, which supports the [`--dbpath` parameter](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption-dbpath) to read from MMAP files directly. This option is only recommended if your data files are from MongoDB 2.6 or older, as there may be features in newer data files that the 2.6 `mongodump` cannot handle correctly. The first approach is likely to be more convenient (and compatible).

There are several features in the 3.4 versions of `mongodump` and `mongorestore` that will help with data migration. In particular: the ability to dump & restore via stdin, [specify namespaces](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#restore-collections-using-wild-cards) to include or exclude when restoring, and [change collection namespaces](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#change-collections-namespaces-during-restore) during restore.

I suggest starting a second `mongod` instance on a new port. If you have a significant amount of data to transfer, you may want to run this on a separate server to avoid RAM and I/O contention between colocated `mongod` processes. Data dumped through `mongodump` will have to be read into memory, and `mongorestore` will write the data and rebuild all indexes on the destination server.

For example:

```
    mongod --dbpath /path/to/mmapfiles --storageEngine mmapv1 --port 28000
```

You can then either:

- Dump individual collections into your 3.4 instance using a command line similar to:

  ```
  mongodump --db test --collection books --port 28000 | mongorestore --port 27017
  ```
- Use the `mongorestore --nsInclude` option with wildcards (`*`) to select a range of collections. For example, all collections in the `test` database starting with `b`:

  ```
  mongodump --db test --port 28000 | mongorestore --port 27017 --nsInclude 'test.b*'
  ```

Comment: Simply downgrading from MongoDB 4.0 to 3.4 was enough for me to be able to run `mongod --dbpath /path/to/mmapfiles`. Thanks for the tip!